# Adding noise to examine a circuit's performance

Tags: noise, ripple

I am interested in adding noise in two circuits, to examine the filters I designed, and the overall performance of the circuit.

I currently have in mind two cases, but I believe in both cases the way to achieve what I want is the same.

In case 1, I would like to induce white noise on a thermistor.

In case 2, I would like to induce some ripple before a regulator.

How can this be achieved? I do not have a signal generator at the time, but I would appreciate to also know how one will have helped, and how it would have to be connected, for future usage.

Answer (score 1):

1) To induce white noise on a thermistor, you can parallel it with a solid carbon resistor at least ten times the thermistor's room temperature value. Solid carbon resistors create a lot of wideband noise.
2) To induce ripple into a power supply use the existing power transformer, or find one that outputs about 6 to 12vac. A wall-pack transformer would work as well. Connect one end to the regulator ground if it is an external transformer.
 Connect a 10uF non-polarized capacitor rated 3 times the voltage before the regulator, to the regulator input. If it is powered by a transformer use the same capacitor but use the transformer output before the rectifier diodes as a source for the ripple. These are simple low cost ways to inject noise. To increase the noise increase the capacitor value.

Answer (score 0):

The two cases you describe are quite different, case 1 can be satisfied with a small amount of energy injected into the circuit - you could easily use the headphone signal from a phone. I would use a resistor to connect the noise signal, sized to give a suitably small level of interference (and to protect your phone).

When you're testing a power circuit, you need to be able to inject a large enough amount of energy. Just connecting a 30mW signal to the input of a voltage regulator, your test signal will vanish into the background. Here you might want to amplify the noise signal to modulate a load current - I think this is easier than trying to generate a low impedance voltage source which you can place in series with the primary supply.